# Ubuntu 11.10- Wine (Understanding Wine)

Tags: 11.10, command-line, windows, wine

I'm new to Ubuntu, I just downloaded "wine" from the command-line. So when and open up "wine", I have no idea what I'm suppose to do next. What do I do after the download had been completed..open it, then what? Let's say I want to download MS Office 2010 (using a disc, will it automatically download it)?

Thanks,
-Vince

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first you get some Windows program (.exe file - say, an installer), then you either start it from terminal using

```
cd /here/the/file/is
wine mywindowsprogram.exe
```

or as I remember you can right-click on an .exe file in Nautilus and choose "Open With..." -> "Wine"

By itself Wine has no interface or anything that can be started, it merely runs Windows programs.

Answer (score 1):

Wine will create a C: drive for you (if it has not you need to run winecfg).  After that you can place the application onto your fake C: drive and run it.  Note that not all programs will run well (or at all) under Wine.  It appears from a quick search that Office will run under wine, but don't expect every Windows application to do so.  The wine faq found here:  http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ goes into good detail on how to use wine.